# I have the error "Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed", what's wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I have a loading provider, and whenver I need to do an async work
I set the loading state to true and at the finish time of asynchronous tasks I set it to false

but when I want to do so I get the error "Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed". what can I do to achieve the goal?

Here is my code :

```
final loadingProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);


class GlobalLoading extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const GlobalLoading({required this.child, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final _entries = useState<List<OverlayEntry?>>([]);
    ref.listen(
      loadingProvider,
      (previous, next) {
        print(previous);
        print(next);
        if (previous == next) return;
        if (next) {
          // Add a modal barrier so the user cannot interact with the app while the loading indicator is visible
          _entries.value.add(OverlayEntry(
            builder: (_) =>
                ModalBarrier(color: AppColors.backGround.withOpacity(0.85)),
          ));
          _entries.value.add(OverlayEntry(
              builder: (_) => Center(
                      child: LoadingAnimationWidget.inkDrop(
                    color: AppColors.secondaries[1],
                    size: 160,
                  ))));
          Overlay.of(context).insertAll(Iterable.generate(
              _entries.value.length, (index) => _entries.value[index]!));
        } else {
          // Remove the modal barrier and loading indicator
          _entries.value.forEach((entry) => entry?.remove());
          _entries.value.clear();
        }
      },
    );
    return child;
  }
}


 GlobalLoading(
            child: SafeArea(
              minimum: EdgeInsets.only(top: height / 15),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    TiTleTile(
                      title: info['nightNumber'] == '0'
                          ? nightNumber
                          : info['title']! + ' $nightNumber',
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: height / 24),
                    Expanded(
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: width / 1.5,
                        // height: height / 1.5,
                        child: ListView.separated(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          cacheExtent: height / 1.64,
                          restorationId: 'night-page',
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          // shrinkWrap: true,
                          // physics: RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: value.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                            print(value.elementAt(index).playerName!);

                            return Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                              children: [
                                if (value.elementAt(index).nightDone != true)
                                  PlayerNameWidget(
                                    playerName: value[index].playerName!,
                                    height: height,
                                    situation: info['situation']!,
                                    nightContext: nightContext,
                                  ),
                                if (value.elementAt(index).nightDone != true)
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: height / 64,
                                  ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            if (value.elementAt(index).nightDone != true)
                              return SizedBox(height: height / 48);
                            return SizedBox();
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    // spacer
                    if (info['button'] != null) SizedBox(height: height / 24),

                    if (info['situation'] == MyStrings.showRoles)
                      MyButton(
                          title: 'go to day',
                          onPressed: () async {
                            ref.read(loadingProvider.notifier).state = true;

                            final isar =
                                await ref.read(isarServiceProvider.future);

                            final yesterday = await isar.getDayNumber();

                            await isar.putGameStatus(
                              dayNumber: yesterday,
                              isDay: true,
                              situation: MyStrings.dayPage,
                            );

                            await ref
                                .read(currentPlayersProvider.notifier)
                                .action(MyStrings.dayPage);

                            nightContext.go('/day/$yesterday');
                            ref.read(loadingProvider.notifier).state = false;
                          }),

                    

....
More
....
....
```

Setting the loading provider's state to false & true But got the provided error

Comment: can you make it minimal by removing other dependencies and others widget.

Comment: Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Answer (score 0):

For this a minimal reproducible code snippet would work for us, but generally speaking this is because the widget has been disposed and you're trying to use the `ref` when the widget itself was disposed.
Some solutions include:

Setting a separate variable and saving it when the widget is disposed so as to keep it alive but Riverpod lint suggests not using `ref` inside `dispose` method.

---

(Preferred) use the mounted property to check if the widget is still mounted in the widget tree by:

```
if(mounted) return;
// * Use ref here as you wish as it is safe to call it here
```

OR

```
if(context.mounted) return;
// * Use ref here as you wish as it is safe to call it here
```

Riverpod FAQ has this covered:
[I have the error "Cannot use "ref" after the widget was disposed", what's wrong?](https://riverpod.dev/docs/essentials/faq#i-have-the-error-cannot-use-ref-after-the-widget-was-disposed-whats-wrong)

Comment: I want to set loading to true then do my async work await for them and then set the loading to false
checking context if it is mounted or not make it only an escape way not getting error but does not solve the problem

**Why is it must be so hard to set a global loading with riverpod ???**

Comment: @BehzadAyubifar can you please add a minimal reproducible code for us to help you at least?

Comment: I will soon, but my whole idea is awaiting on some futures or some async funcs and then set loading to false then do routing for example
but in this situation apparently widget is disposed (I wonder why it gets unmounted while still doing tasks in onPressed method)

Comment: this is pretty easy and straightforward as you say, but there's some logic you're missing.

Comment: I don't know how to write a code so you can reproduce it because my own project is kinda complex

Comment: "global loading" is a code smell.  Instead, you should be using async providers that can individually return a loading state, and trigger updates to their consuming UIs.